# setValue dynamic to object in angular7

Tags: angular, typescript, object, refactoring

I have this code which I want to refactor to better solution:

```
    async onServerRequestForDraft(res: { value: {}; tabType: ETabType; }) {
        res.value = this.uiForm.value;
       
        res.value = this.data;
       res.value['brokerage'] = this.uiForm.value.brokerage != null ? this.uiForm.value.brokerage : { id: 0, name: null };
        res.value['org'] = this.uiForm.value.org; 
        res.value['selectedPhone'] = this.uiForm.value.selectedPhone || '';
        res.value['customerName'] = this.uiForm.value.customerName || '';
}
```

I can't use forEach because res is not an array. maybe another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need forEach for it to work though you can use it.

```
   async onServerRequestForDraft(res: { value: {}, tabType: ETabType }) {
      Object.assign(res.value, {
          'brokerage': this.uiForm.value.brokerage ?? { id: 0, name: null },
          'org': this.uiForm.value.selectedPhone ?? '',
          'customerName': this.uiForm.value.customerName ?? '';
      })

      return res;
}
```

If you want to use loop only, you can do it this way:

```
async onServerRequestForDraft(res: { value: {}, tabType: ETabType }) {

     for (const key in this.uiForm.value) {
         if (key === 'brokerage') {
          Object.assign(res.value, {key : this.uiForm.value[key] ?? { id: 0, name: null }});
          continue;
         }
         Object.assign(res.value, {key : this.uiForm.value[key] ?? ''});
      }
      

      return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! maybe you have solution for refactoring similiar code: `uiFormInit(value: CustomerInfoForestOfficerModel) {
    if (value.contactName) {
      this.contactName = value.contactName;
      this.uiCtr.contactName.setValue(this.contactName);
    }
    if (value.contactPhone) {
      this.contactPhone = value.contactPhone;
      this.uiCtr.contactPhone.setValue(this.contactPhone);
    }
}` and so on for all of the value items..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u can use forEach on Object like this :

```
Object.entries(this.uiForm.value).forEach((item) => {
    // item[0]  object key
    // item[1]  object value
 });
```